# flink - inject values into flatmap

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

Situation: multiple identical kafka datasources that get flatmapped into tuples for later union, reduction, saving, whatnot.

I need to know which original datasource each flatmapped packet came from to tag in the tuple. I'd rather not have a separate **FlatMapFunction** for each datasource as there may be hundreds.

Ideally I'd be able to pass some value into the flatmap function to add to the resultant tuple.

Possible? Some other way to achieve this?

Comment: Does this mean you have a loop when you plug the job together that adds a lot of sources that get flatmapped with different operators? Or do you have many parallel instances of the same source and flatmap and each instance should add a different tag?

Comment: I have many parallel sources of the *same type* of data. I need to identify each source when I store it. Each source gets treated the same way.

Comment: I can override the constructor for FlatMap and pass in a value for the kafka datasource. It's a sufficient solution for now. This begs the question though: when combining many sources - what's the most efficient way? If my topology is `kafka->flatmap->reduce->map (write to db)` and I want to do this to many sources - where should I put the **union** step?

Comment: I think there is confusion in terminology. If I say "instance of an operator" I do mean the parallel instances (ie, tasks) Flink starts. It seems you have multiple operator (that "accidentally" uses the same FlatMapFunction). Correct my if I am wrong. So configuring the operators differently via constructor arguments is a good way to go. An an alternative you could use "broadcast variables". https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Variables+Closures+vs.+Broadcast+Variables

Comment: About the **union**: it depends on your semantics... if you do it *before* the reduce step, the partitions are built over all sources -- if you do it *after* the reduce, you get partitions per source. Thus, if two sources emit a tuple with the same key, they end up in different partitions... Doing the using before flatmap disallows flatmap to get chained with the source -- I would expect a performance penalty if chaining is prohibited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have multiple source operators, you can simply configure the different sources via constructor arguments. As an alternative, you could also use *broadcast variables*: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/Variables+Closures+vs.+Broadcast+Variables

**About union**: it depends on your semantics you need. If you do it *before* the `reduce` step, the partitions are built over all sources -- if you do it *after* the reduce, you get partitions per source. Thus, if two sources emit a tuple with the same key, they end up in different partitions. Doing the union before `flatMap` disallows `flatMap` to get chained with the source -- I would expect a performance penalty if chaining is prohibited.